# Python intra-package references not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I'm struggling to work with intra-package references. Here is the documentation that I'm following https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references

I'm doing a little test with this:

```
test/
    __init__.py
    module_a/
        __init__.py
        script_a.py
            ( from test.module_b import script_b )
    module_b/
        __init__.py
        script_b.py
            ( def something(): print("something") )
```

but my imports are not working and this error is arising

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError
No module named 'test'
File "/Users/nacho/Desktop/test/module_a/script_a.py", line 1, in <module>
from test.module_b import script_b
```

what am I doing wrong?

I'm not using any framework. just plain python 3.9 with this command

```
python3 script_a.py
```

I have not installed the test package o used the -m switch.

Regards!

Comment: How are you running `python`? Please include the full command. Did you install the `test` package? Are you running from the directory containing `test`? Did you use the `-m` switch?

Comment: Hi! thanks for commenting! I edited the question with that new info. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the package `test` is not found on Python's [import paths](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path). You have (at least) four options to resolve this:

1. Run the script from the directory that *contains* the `test` directory, i.e. `python test/module_a/script_a.py`. This way *all* imports used within the `test` package must be absolute, i.e. of the form `from test.module_b import script_b` (rather than `from ..module_b import script_b`).
2. Run the package via the [`-m` switch](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m), also from the directory containing the `test` directory: `python -m test.module_a`. You would need to provide an additional [`__main__.py`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) file inside `module_a` that invokes the desired functionality. This way you can also use relative imports, i.e. `.` and `..`.
3. [Install the whole package](https://packaging.python.org/) and then you can run it from the command line from anywhere (using the steps described in (2)).
4. Modify [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) to point to the directory containing `test`: `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/test python script_a.py`.